# python no me carga una imagen solo aparece un cuadro blanco

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

hola disculpan creo que este es un problema muy recurrente y lo que pasa es que de la nada python dejo de cargarme las imagenes, tengo instalado tk y pil, el problema es que si reconose la imagen por que el cuadro toma el tamaño que tiene la imagen en pixeles pero no se ve la imagen como tal. ojala me puedan ayudar para saber que esta pasando

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry("950x660+0+0")
window.config(bg="blue")
window.title("tejon")
 
boton=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\LaCuevitaDel Tejon\\tejon 1 guif.gif")
boton=Label(window, image=boton).place(x=0, y=0, width=600, height=400 )

window.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo una hipotesis de lo que puede estar pasando, pero para poder hacer pruebas, podrías poner el código como texto por favor? No creo que nadie aquí quiera transcribir el código de tu imagen. De paso así tu pregunta será mejor recibida. Por favor lee https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: Hay unos espacios en el nombre del archivo que no se ven en el código que compartes. El nombre del archivo es diferente. Seguro que es el mismo código? Eso puede ser la causa del problema...

Comment: tienes razon pero esos espacios los he deber puesto en el ultimo momento de publicarlo sin querer deja lo corrijo pero si es el mismo codigo

Comment: ya lo corregi disculpen ustedes, es que tambien lo segui trabajando por que antes de que surgiera el problema todo estaba funcionando perfecto... ya hasta reinstale el python y no se arregla

Comment: tienes razon @DanteS. disculpa soy nuevo en esto y aun paso por alto muchas cosas gracias por el consejo ojala puedan ayudarme a resolver este problema tan "curioso"

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

Este error es muy común. No estoy seguro de por que sucede (creo que tiene que ver con el recolector de basura de Python).

Primero guardas la imagen en la variable boton, pero luego reemplazas el valor de dicha variable por un widget button. Entonces ya no hay nada referenciando a la imagen.
El error que describes ocurre cuando no existen referencias a la imagen. Es decir, cuando ninguna variable almacena la imagen.

#### Solución

Simplemente guarda la imagen en una variable de nombre diferente a la que usas para almacenar al botón.

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry("950x660+0+0")
window.config(bg="blue")
window.title("tejon")
 
boton_img=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Victor\\Desktop\\LaCuevitaDel Tejon\\tejon 1 guif.gif")
boton=Label(window, image=boton_img).place(x=0, y=0, width=600, height=400 )

window.mainloop()
```

#### El caso de la imagen creada en una función

Si creas la imagen dentro de una función puede ocurrir el mismo error, ya que al finalizar la función, todas las variables creadas dentro son eliminadas. Para mantener una referencia a la imagen tienes dos caminos:

Primero decirle a la función que la variable donde quieres guardar la imagen es global:

```
def creaboton():
    global boton_img
    
    boton_img=PhotoImage(file="imagen.png")
    boton=Label(window, image=boton_img).place(x=0, y=0, width=600, height=400 )
```

Segundo, un método en mi opinión más seguro. Si la función es un método de clase. Es decir, es una función dentro de una clase. Puedes guardar la imagen como un atributo de dicha clase. Claramente esto te obligará a que la instancia de dicha clase siga existiendo en el ambito global.

```
def creaboton(Self):
    Self.boton_img=PhotoImage(file="imagen.png")
    boton=Label(window, image=Self.boton_img).place(x=0, y=0, width=600, height=400 )
```